# "connected, self updating" rows in sql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to mySql. I am working on a project, where I want to do evaluations on the economic efficiency of certain goods in python. For my first tries, I held my data in a csv-file. I now want to move on to a solid database solution and decided I would use mySql.

The dada consists for example of the following columns
id, GoodName, GoodWeightRaw, GoodWeightProcessed, RawMaterial, SellingPrice.

The "problem" is, that there are simple goods and there are combined goods.

Say:
id 1 - copper
id 2 - plastics

Somewhere further down we might have
id 50 - copper cable

Copper Cables are made from copper and plastics - therefore the RawMaterial of id50 would be the goods id1 and id2. Also the RawWeight of the copper cables would be the proccesed weight of copper + the processed weight of plastics.

In the csv file I use at the moment those values have all been "hard coded" and if some values of the basic materials change, I would have to look up in which combined goods they are used and change the values by hand accordingly.

I wonder wether there is a way in sql to automaticly compute values in a row from values in another row, as well as have them updated every time the other rows change.

---

So far I tried:

First I thought I might create two tables for basic and combined goods, however the combined goods would still not update themselfes.

I found out, that I can create table rows from SELECT statements, and create combined goods from a combination of basic goods this way. However those rows are also "permanent" once created and would still have to be updated manually.

So is there a clean best practice in SQL for rows, created from other rows and then updated accordingly when the correlating rows are changed?

Comment: About the only clean way I can think to implement something like this is to have all you're update operations handled by stored procedure. A trigger cannot be used because it cannot modify it's own table (outside of the triggering row). That said, perhaps you should calculate the final values as needed, it seems odd to me that a copper pan with a plastic handle would have the same values as a copper wire sheathed in plastic, so I would think you would store "units" of the parts.

Comment: Are there only ever two raw materials per 'good'

Comment: @Strawberry no, there might be everything from 1 to lets say 10 raw materials per good